# How to order elements in Grid View

Tags: android, xml, gridview

I have a Grid View adapter where all is in this code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = convertView; 
    CheckBox check = null;
    ImageView pic = null;

    if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
                                // attributes
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.check_box_and_imageview, null);
     } 

    pic = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    check = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    check.setTag(position);

    ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader(mContext);

    //this loads image from given url
    loader.DisplayImage(url[position], pic);
    return v;



}
```

Here i create a view with check box and image view. There is the problem because image view is different size and gridview make aligment by both size checkbox and image view. But i want to order element by check box.

For better explanation what i want to do will show this pic:

[image]

This i want to do. How ever my image views isn't all same size. Now i will illustrate how it looks:

[image]

So this don't suite me. I want to make alignment not all checkbox and imageview. But just that check boxes would be under checks boxes.

So isn't this possible to do with gird view ?

Comment: use the dimensions for loader image like 60x60 etc.and use scaletype  like  loader.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

Comment: can't we align the all grid element left align which make so check boxes would be under checks boxes.......

Answer (score 0):

- Check if the convertView is null:
- If it is null it's time to inflate a new View for this GridView's element. You could also use the holder pattern to cache looking for the composing Views(instead of searching with findViewById everytime)(You use the setTag element for the inflated View but it's a piece of data from the Node data element ?!? What do you plan to do with it?!?)